# merge 2 txt file in linux

Tags: linux, merge, paste, cat

file1

```
1
2
3
4
```

file2

```
5
6
7
8
```

result I want

```
1   
5
2
6
3
7
4
8
```

which file1 alternative with file2

**not like**

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

can I merge file like this?

Comment: `cat file1 file2`. If you want to save the output in another file, `cat file1 file2 > file3`

Comment: @bisen2 in that casse it will just add file 2 after file1 isn't it ?  that''s like what I wanted...

Comment: totally right, I should have read the question more carefully. You can use `paste -d \\n file1 file2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to the `sed` method suggested by @Michael, you can also use the `paste` command, in this case: `paste -d \\n file1 file2`

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the below in the linux command line?

```
cat file2.txt >> file1.txt
```

This will append the text in file1 to file 2.

Edit: Having seen your query is referring to intertwining the files, I think this article will help you using the 'sed' command: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/288521/with-the-linux-cat-command-how-do-i-show-only-certain-lines-by-number

Comment: yes I aleady did, but in that case it will just add up file2 after file1

Comment: if you see sample up there 1st line of file2 is appended after 1st line of file 2 then 2nd line after 2nd and so on ..., but with cat command it will just add each file

Comment: I have now edited my response with an article on using the 'sed' command. You can use this to merge with bisen2's solution.